# How to pick out individual numbers from the text file?

Tags: java

For a project, I'm creating a sudoku solver. I'm required to get the info from a file that I call in the command line (i.e. the command line holds the path to the text file containing the sudoku puzzle). My approach was going to be to add up every row, column, and 3x3 box to verify that it equals 45 (1 through 9 added up). Since 1-9 must be in each row, column, AND 3x3, at least one of those will total incorrect if there is a duplicate number or one is missing.

However, the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to pick out individual numbers from the text file. I'm using

```
File f = new File(args[0]);
```

to pull the file into my project but I don't know how to access specific elements from it. Ideas?

EDIT: The file is a .txt file and looks like this...

```
1 4 5 3 2 7 6 9 8
8 3 9 6 5 4 1 2 7
6 7 2 9 1 8 5 4 3
4 9 6 1 8 5 3 7 2
2 1 8 4 7 3 9 5 6
7 5 3 2 9 6 4 8 1
3 6 7 5 4 2 8 1 9
9 8 4 7 6 1 2 3 5
5 2 1 8 3 9 7 6 4
```

Would this work to access each number in the numbers array?

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   sum +=numbers [i] 
}
```

Comment: This is a problem with file parsing.  Describe how the specific lines of the file look and we can give you more specific answers.

Comment: @La-comadreja Edited

Comment: Hooray! The sudoku in the input file is already solved!

Comment: @Paulpro That's aside the point, I just need the program to tell me it's right ;)

Comment: @RyanDorman I'm just being silly. A more important point is that your idea of testing that everything sums to `45` is insufficient to conclude that the sudoku problem is correctly solved. Consider a grid full of `5`s everywhere. It will pass your test, but obviously isn't a good sudoku solution. You will need to actually check that every element is distinct and from 1-9 in each row, column, and 3x3 subsquare.

Comment: @Paulpro If that's the case then I'm completely lost on how I would attempt that...

Comment: @RyanDorman Well you could create a method that takes an array of 9 integers (or chars) as input and verifies that each number 1-9 is found in the array. If each number is found and there are only `9` entries in the array, then all 9 must be distinct, so it is a valid set of 9 numbers (whether it be a row, column, or 3x3 square).

Comment: Then you can loop through the rows and for each row fill an array with the 9 values in the row and call the function on it, then loop through the columns and do the same thing, and then the 3x3 squares. If at any time your function returns `false` you know that your solution is invalid. If it returns true every time and you get to the end of your 3x3 loop, then the sudoku solution is valid.

Comment: @RyanDorman Your idea of summing to 45 was great by the way. Even though it wouldn't fully work for this problem. It's always good to try to think of a reduction to a simpler problem and it's good that you're thinking in that way already. Coming up with an better way to solve a problem before beginning to code the solution is a very valuable skill. You'll also need to be able to verify that the reduction is valid for all inputs, which is a skill you will develop.

Comment: I don't want you to think that you should avoid looking for shortcuts like that because this one didn't work out. In general it's a great idea and will get you ahead in the long run.

Comment: @Paulpro Do you know how I could access each number as I described, though? I'm mostly looking to get this over with since I'm very very very close to the deadline but I do really like what you've described.

Comment: I would use a loop something like `int[][] grid = new int[9][9]; for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) { for ( int j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) { if ( ! scanner.hasNextInt() ) { // exit with error since it couldn't read all 81 integers } grid[i][j] = scanner.nextInt(); } }`

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer though. I don't know if I got the syntax fully right, or if that would even compile, but I would expect it to read the full grid into a 9x9 array, so that grid[0][0], grid[0][1], .. is the first row, and `grid[1][0], grid[1][1], ...` is the next row.

Comment: @Paulpro YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER. Thank you so much! I've been struggling for the past couple hours trying to get this and you helped immensely!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, Ryan. I'll post my comments as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the numbers into a 2D array like so:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);

int[][] grid = new int[9][9];

for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) {
        if ( ! scanner.hasNextInt() ) {
             // exit with error since it couldn't read all 81 integers 
        }
        // read next integer into 9x9 grid array
        grid[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

then you should validate each row, column, and relevant 3x3 subsquare. Checking that each one sums to 45 is insufficient (consider a grid full of 5's which passes that test, but is obviously incorrect), so you need to validate that each one contains each distinct value from 1 through 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the individual lines of the file as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
}
scan.close();
```

With each line, you'll need to split it by the delimiter.  See new line added to the scan loop:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
}
```

For each line, you've been able to extract the numbers into a string array.

You can convert the numbers to integers as follows:

```
String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
for (String e : numbers) int num = Integer.parseInt(e);
```

You'd probably want to save previous lines into a data structure, though.   If the puzzle is Sudoku, you can read the numbers into an integer matrix.  Then you can perform the Sudoku calculations to verify that the puzzle was solved, as the problem describes, and presumably print the results.

Comment: How would I be able to access the first 3 numbers in the first 3 rows to add them up as well as adding the first number of each row together to check vertically?

Comment: Can you give an example on how I would add up the first 3 numbers in the first 3 rows (meaning the most left upper 3x3)? For some reason I'm struggling to see this.